# Не работают элементы jquery ui при открытии окна во второй раз

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте!

Есть у меня два файла - index.php и form.php. В index размещен блок контента `<div id = "content"></div>`, а в form.php - форма на jquery ui и её обработка.

Форма вызывается через загрузку страницы в контент: `$("#content").load("form.php")` **через ссылку** на главной странице. При первоначальном открытии формы всё работает. А при закрытии и повторном открытии её все элементы, связанные с jquery, перестают работать. Почему так происходит? Такой вопрос.

**Обновление**

```
<script>

// Документ готов

 jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
    // .. ТУТ КОД ОКНА

    // ОБРАБОТЧИКИ  
    $( "#region" ).autocomplete(
    {
        source: "region.php",

    });

    $( "#personal" ).button()
    .click(function( event )
    {
        swal( "Персонал" );
    });

});
</script>
```

Таким образом через id.

Comment: А как устанавливаются обработчики для этих элементов?

Comment: <script>
// Документ готов!
 jQuery(document).ready(function()
{
 // .. ТУТ КОД ОКНА
 
 // ОБРАБОТЧИКИ 
 $( "#region" ).autocomplete(
 {
  source: "region.php",
   
 });
    
 $( "#personal" ).button()
 .click(function( event )
 {
     swal( "Персонал" );
 });
   
   
});
</script>

Таким образом через id.

Answer (score 1):

При изменении DOM дерева все event'ы "отвязываются" от своих элементов. Посмотрите в сторону on

http://api.jquery.com/on/

т.е. $('a').click(); // не будет работать

а $(document).on('a', 'click', function()); // будет